# How to debug dynamic workflows (with custom activities)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I'm trying to debug a dynamic loaded workflow. For that basically I've implemented following steps:

```
var currentWorkflow = ActivityXamlServices.Load(@"d:\test.xaml");
var wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(currentWorkflow, anyInputs);
wfApp.Run();
```

Now I want to debug the activities of the workflow step by step - if possible within the workflow designer. In MSDN I found an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb483168%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) how to set Breakpoints in Workflows on the Debug menu,

> 1. On the Debug menu, select New Breakpoint.
> 2. Click Break at Function. The New Breakpoint dialog box opens.
> 3. Specify the name of an activity in the Function text box using this syntax: **QualifiedActivityId[:[FullClassName][:InstanceId]]**.
>
> ...

but I haven't any idea how to specify the name of an activity in the Function text box and how to get the QualifiedActivityId.

**Can anyone give an example?**

Another problem is that I have many custom activities within the loose xaml, which within the designer are displayed by red boxes with following message: *"Activity could not be loaded because of errors in the XAML*". Is there a way to load relevant assemblies so that VS2010 can display loose xamls with custom activities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this:

- Load the XAML into VisualStudio (in your case, d:\test.xaml)
- Set a breakpoint inside the workflow (simply select an activity and press F9)
- Start the application that contains your wfApp.Run() line in the VS debugger (F5)
- As soon as your application loads the xaml and runs it, your breakpoint will be hit and you can inspect WF variables, step over the next activities etc.

So nothing special at all, without specifying the activity by name, simply click and select.

In the real world, I always have some testcases that run the code, so I simply use the "Test -> Debug -> Test in current context" option from VS2010, not the F5 key. Put the cursor inside your test method, then press Ctrl-R Ctrl-T (this is the default binding for that action).
Alternatively, if you have ReSharper installed, you can click on the Debugger button in the "Unit Test Sessions" window.

Comment: Hi @Achim! Thanks for your answer. Your way works after editing and saving the loose xaml in vs2010. Then there was a new attribute within the root sequence tag with an absolute path (<Sequence **sad:XamlDebuggerXmlReader.FileName**="d:\test.xaml"). I think i will get a problem here, when I load xamls later dynamicly from database. But I'm not sure, if it is possible for vs2010 to load the xaml from stream for debugging, if I specify the activity by name. What do you think?

Comment: Another problem is that I have many custom activities within the workflow and they are skipped while debugging (they also cannot be displayed within the designer - instead of them there are red boxes with this message: Activity could not be loaded because of errors in the XAML). Is there a way to load relevant assemblies so that VS2010 can display loose xamls with custom activities.

Comment: VS2010 has a lot of problems with that indeed. Usually I get it to work if the Xaml file is included in a C# project, that project has references to all assemblies that include the used custom activities, and in the xaml all namespace declarations contain an assembly= part. If you create the Xaml in VS the assembly part is usually missing for some namespaces (namely those that are part of the project where you have your xaml) and that might cause problems when debugging.

Comment: I don't know about the absolute path, sorry. It's alwas a pain when MS adds absolute pathes into files like this, but I did not encounter any problems so far with the debugger tag.

Comment: Ok, I think I will debug the xaml files using an additional project with all the references - without checking in xaml files into TFS. Thanks.